# How to create separate nodes for each column in a spreadsheet using Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, csv

I have an excel file containing lot of columns. I want to create a graph database in Neo4J with all these columns as a separate node so that I can establish relationship between them and play around with the cypher query to get to know my data quite well. I did write a cypher query to make each column as a node, but when I run the relationship query it shows me the name of one node and gives a random number for all the related nodes despite changing the **captions in the properties** section.

Sample Create statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File Location" AS row CREATE (:NodeName {DATE_OCCURED: row.Date});
```

Query to visualize the relationship between nodes:

```
MATCH (a)-[:`REL NAME`]->(b) RETURN a,b LIMIT 25;
```

This gives me the values the node "a" and random numbers for all the node "b". I don't know where I am going wrong. I thought it has something to do with the way the data has been set up in my file. So I created a file for each column of my main file and wrote the create statements to get the nodes. I still don't get the actual values of the related nodes.

[image: Sample output for the relationship query]